# Angular ActivatedRoute data is unchanged when injecting into a dynamically created component

Tags: angular

My Angular app consists of a main viewport and a right hand panel that is an "aside" to the main viewport. Clicking on certain things in the main viewport cause this right panel to open/close and I am using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` from `@angular/core` in order to dynamically create my panel components and provide them with data. Up until now this has all worked great, but I recently noticed that when I try to inject `ActivatedRoute` into these components' ctor the initial instantiation works fine and I get my route data as I expect. However, if I pivot the app to the same view from another context (e.g. I go from order A to order B in the URI which will trigger all my routes to be re-created) and inspect the `ActivatedRoute` data, the value of the `BehaviorSubject` that holds the route data is unchanged.

This seems to work fine for my regular components that are apart of the normal `<router-outlet>`, but its just these dynamically created components that never seem to get updated.

I have confirmed that the components are being destroyed as the `ngOnDestroy()` method is running and the ctor is called again each time I pivot to a new order.

There must be something special regarding dynamically created components that cause this to not work as expected. Are you not supposed to be able to inject the `ActivatedRoute` into a component that isn't created  by the router? If so, that is less than ideal but I could find other ways to fix it.

**EDIT**

Here is my code used to render the component

```
render(component: PanelViewPackage, outlet: PanelViewportOutlet): ComponentRef<any> {

    outlet.viewContainerRef.detach();

    if (!component.hasState()) {
      let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.Config.Component);

      let componentRef = outlet.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

      // There seems to be 2 ways to create this component... is one way better than the other?
      // let componentRef = componentFactory.create(outlet.viewContainerRef.parentInjector);

      (<PanelViewportComponentBase<any>>componentRef.instance).applyResolve(component.Config.Resolver);
      (<PanelViewportComponentBase<any>>componentRef.instance).applyRejector(component.Config.Rejector);
      (<PanelViewportComponentBase<any>>componentRef.instance).applyData(component.Config.Data);

      return componentRef;

    } else {
      let componentRef = component.getComponentRef();
      outlet.viewContainerRef.insert(componentRef.hostView);

      return componentRef;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please update your question with source code that demonstrates the problem. I want to see what injector you are using with the component factories.

Comment: @cgTag I updated with some of my code. If you look at the comment I noticed there are 2 way to create a component. You can use the `ViewContainerRef` to create the component by passing in the factory or you can use the factory and pass in the injector of the `ViewContainerRef`. Do these do the same thing?